# Trying to Authenticate using Username/Password Flow not working

Tags: authentication, developer

really hoping someone can get me track here as this is really holding me up.  Thank you for reading...

I have a SF Dev account and am trying to learn how to create a basic integration to gather customer info from my dev Salesforce account.  I have tried almost every tutorial on the Internet but no luck, so I am thinking I am missing a step.

I have created a Connected App and enabled OAuth.  I have collected the Consumer Key/Secret and I have a valid Security Token.

If I run the following Console App I get the following error:

[image]

**Here is my class:**

```
namespace ForceConnect
{
    class Program
    {
        private static readonly string SecurityToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecurityToken"];
        private static readonly string ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerKey"];
        private static readonly string ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConsumerSecret"];
        private static readonly string Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
        private static readonly string Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"] + SecurityToken;
        private static readonly string IsSandboxUser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IsSandboxUser"];

        static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                var task = RunSample();
                task.Wait();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);

                var innerException = e.InnerException;
                while (innerException != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(innerException.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(innerException.StackTrace);

                    innerException = innerException.InnerException;
                    Console.Read();
                }
            }
        }

        private static async Task RunSample()
        {
            var auth = new AuthenticationClient();

            // Authenticate with Salesforce
            Console.WriteLine("Authenticating with Salesforce");
            var url = IsSandboxUser.Equals("true", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                ? "https://test.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token"
            : "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token";

            await auth.UsernamePasswordAsync(ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret, Username, Password+SecurityToken,url);
            Console.WriteLine("Connected to Salesforce");

            var client = new ForceClient(auth.InstanceUrl, auth.AccessToken, auth.ApiVersion);

            // retrieve all accounts
            Console.WriteLine("Get Accounts");

            const string qry = "SELECT ID, Name FROM Account";
            var accts = new List<Account>();
            var results = await client.QueryAsync<Account>(qry);
            var totalSize = results.TotalSize;

            Console.WriteLine("Queried " + totalSize + " records.");

            accts.AddRange(results.Records);
            var nextRecordsUrl = results.NextRecordsUrl;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextRecordsUrl))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found nextRecordsUrl.");

                while (true)
                {
                    var continuationResults = await client.QueryContinuationAsync<Account>(nextRecordsUrl);
                    totalSize = continuationResults.TotalSize;
                    Console.WriteLine("Queried an additional " + totalSize + " records.");

                    accts.AddRange(continuationResults.Records);
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(continuationResults.NextRecordsUrl)) break;

                    //pass nextRecordsUrl back to client.QueryAsync to request next set of records
                    nextRecordsUrl = continuationResults.NextRecordsUrl;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Retrieved accounts = " + accts.Count() + ", expected size = " + totalSize);

            // Create a sample record
            Console.WriteLine("Creating test record.");
            var account = new Account { Name = "Test Account" };
                //account.Id = await client.CreateAsync(Account.SObjectTypeName, account);
                var response = await client.CreateAsync("Account", account);
            string Id = response.Id;

            if (account.Id == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to create test record.");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Successfully created test record.");

            // Update the sample record
            // Shows that annonymous types can be used as well
            Console.WriteLine("Updating test record.");
            var success = await client.UpdateAsync(Account.SObjectTypeName, account.Id, new { Name = "Test Update" });
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(success.Errors.ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to update test record!");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Successfully updated the record.");

            // Retrieve the sample record
            // How to retrieve a single record if the id is known
            Console.WriteLine("Retrieving the record by ID.");
            account = await client.QueryByIdAsync<Account>(Account.SObjectTypeName, account.Id);
            if (account == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to retrieve the record by ID!");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Retrieved the record by ID.");

            // Query for record by name
            Console.WriteLine("Querying the record by name.");
            var accounts = await client.QueryAsync<Account>("SELECT ID, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = '" + account.Name + "'");
            account = accounts.Records.FirstOrDefault();
            if (account == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to retrieve account by query!");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Retrieved the record by name.");

            // Delete account
            Console.WriteLine("Deleting the record by ID.");
            var deleted = await client.DeleteAsync(Account.SObjectTypeName, account.Id);
            if (!deleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to delete the record by ID!");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Deleted the record by ID.");

            // Selecting multiple accounts into a dynamic
            Console.WriteLine("Querying multiple records.");
            var dynamicAccounts = await client.QueryAsync<dynamic>("SELECT ID, Name FROM Account LIMIT 10");
            foreach (dynamic acct in dynamicAccounts.Records)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Account - " + acct.Name);
            }

            // Creating parent - child records using a Dynamic
            Console.WriteLine("Creating a parent record (Account)");
            dynamic a = new ExpandoObject();
            a.Name = "Account from .Net Toolkit";
            a.Id = await client.CreateAsync("Account", a);
            if (a.Id == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to create parent record.");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Creating a child record (Contact)");
            dynamic c = new ExpandoObject();
            c.FirstName = "Joe";
            c.LastName = "Blow";
            c.AccountId = a.Id;
            c.Id = await client.CreateAsync("Contact", c);
            if (c.Id == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to create child record.");
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Deleting parent and child");

            // Delete account (also deletes contact)
            Console.WriteLine("Deleting the Account by Id.");
            deleted = await client.DeleteAsync(Account.SObjectTypeName, a.Id);
            if (!deleted)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to delete the record by ID!");
                return;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Deleted the Account and Contact.");

        }

        private class Account
        {
            public const String SObjectTypeName = "Account";

            public String Id { get; set; }
            public String Name { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I enter the following in my REST Client I get a 200: OK Status. https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token&grant_type=password&client_id=<ClientId>
&client_secret=<ConsumerSecret>&username=<username>&password=<password+SecretToken>

Comment: What is the value of the sandbox variable? If this is a dev org, the sandbox value needs to be set to False.

Comment: It is a Dev account not a Sandbox.  I can see when I set a breakpoint that the token URL is the https://login...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "useful" part of the exception reporting is the message:

> retry your request

From my Googling, others who have experienced that error have had success in changing the oauth2 url from `login.` to `ap1.` (or whatever instance they are on).

References:

- [username/Password authentication, {"error":"unknown_error","error_description":"retry your request"}](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008tiFIAQ)
- [username & password OAuth Request returning error](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gmXOAAY)

If changing the URL to your specfic instance works **and** the equavalient direct REST call to `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` works then it is most likely an issue with the [Force.com toolkit for .NET](https://github.com/developerforce/Force.com-Toolkit-for-NET)

For good measure, also check your [Login History](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_login_history.htm&siteLang=en_US&type=0) in the Setup pages. It might provide more clues in the Status column.

Comment: Thank you Daniel!!  This didn't quite get me up and running, because I hit a couple more issues, but you fixed this issue.  For anyone else using the sample Force.com Toolkit for .Net Sample (Console App).  You don't need to append the Security Token to the Password and you need to add the following before the await call:  ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: @RichardHamlyn I am kind of surprised nobody has updated the Toolkit yet. This is something that we have been doing in our C# code since salesforce swithced off TLS 1.0.